# How to plot the data I read from a file in R?

Tags: r, plot

Our instructor assigned us with typing a R script. We don't have any study paper or source for the codes that the instructor typed on class so I'm trying to get help from the articles on internet but I still couldn't find a guide for what I need. Please don't get me wrong, I don't request for someone to do my homework I'm just looking for some tips or any guide links that can help me. When I search on google, not all of the results are related to this and they are usually not helping me or too complicated. The assignment is:

- Read data from a .txt file. (I researched and learned how to read data but my problem is I don't know which type of data should I type on the text file to make it plottable by average, standart deviation, histogram etc.)
- On the first screen, plot the data, plot the average and plot the standart deviation as line
- on the second screen, plot a line from corner to corner and sort the values on it
- third screen, plot the data as histogram and plot the distribution function on it
- 4th screen, plot the anomaly and anomaly line = 0, then make the values that are higher than the anomaly line with different pch than the ones that is lower
- finally get the png of 4 screens (i found how to do this)
  Thanks.

Comment: There were no books assigned for the class? Given the scope of this assignment, it's difficult to believe that there hasn't been a lead up to this assignment.

Comment: This is a very usefull guide: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf

Comment: @SantiagoHurtado I disagree. For one thing it’s severely outdated. For another, it starts off with lots of irrelevant low-level details. That’s a bad way of teaching. I recommend a modern approach, e.g.*R for Data Science* by Grolemund and Wickham instead.

Answer (score 1):

*Which type of data?*

You should use metric data. For example the height/age of pople.

For example let's assuhe you have a dataframe `yourDataframe`:

```
height
160
155
176
153
185
```

*On the first screen, plot the data*

You can use R's standard plot function there: `lines(yourDataframe$height)`

*plot the average and plot the standart deviation*

There are already function for those things (for example `mean(yourDataframe$height)`). Just ask Google.
You can add those values to your linechart using `points(mean(yourDataframe$height))`.

I think after you did this you will be able to solve the rest of your assignment by yourself. R has quite a big community and you will find everything you need by googling. I guess this is how most people learn R.